# $\sum_{k=0}^{2016}(1+ \omega^k)^{2017}\ $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, summation

Let $\omega  \ $be a root of the polynomial $\ x^{2016} +x^{2015}+x^{2014}+...+x+1=0  \ $. Then find the value of the following sum: $$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}(1+ \omega^k)^{2017}\ $$

Well I have simplified the expression as:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}(1+ 2017\omega^k)\ $$ after that i further simplified it as 
$$\ 2016+2017\sum_{k=0}^{2016}(\omega^k)\ $$ but after this i am unable to proceed.

Comment: What an interesting question.  Have you made any attempts to solve it?  Where did you find it?

Comment: well the question was given to me by a teacher as a HW

Comment: Yeah i have made an attempt to solve it but i m getting the wrong answer

Comment: How do you know it is wrong? Think you should edit the question and point out where you think you may have taken a bender.

Comment: How did you conclude $\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\left(1+\omega^k\right)^{2017} = \sum_{k=0}^{2016}\left(1+2017\omega^k\right)$? Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: Fanciful, I'll wager.

Comment: Somehow that exponent $\;2017\;$ became a coefficient, a little a la de Moivre...I don't think this is correct, though.

Comment: This is an approximation done using differentiation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing to note is that 2017 is prime so that for $k\ne 0$ or $2017$ the numbers $1,\omega^k,\omega^{2k},\dots,\omega^{2016k}$ are just a rearrangement of $1,\omega,\omega^2,\dots,\omega^{2016}$ and hence sum to 0.

For each $k$ we expand by the binomial theorem. The zero powers are each ${2017\choose 0}$ and so summed over $k$ they sum to $2017$. The $2017$th powers are each ${2017\choose 2017}$ and also sum to $2017$. But all the other powers sum to 0. So the grand total is just $4034$.

Answer (score 2):

> Let $\omega=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}{ n}\right)$ be the $n$-th root of unity. The following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\omega^k\right)^n=2n
> \end{align*}
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\omega^k\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\omega^{kj}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\omega^j\right)^k\\
> &=2n+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(\omega^j\right)^k\tag{1}\\
> &=2n+\sum_{{j=1}\atop{j\nmid n}}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}\frac{1-\omega^{nj}}{1-\omega^j}\tag{2}\\
> &=2n
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we separate the summands $j=0$ and $j=n$
- In (2) we use $\omega^n=1$ and have to respect that the sum is zero if $j\mid n$

Comment: How is $\;e^{2\pi n }\;$ an $\;n-$ th root of unity?? Even multiplying the exponent by $\;i\;$ ?

Comment: Nice, although $\omega_n = \exp(2\pi i k / n)$. Also, you will get $0/0$ in your sum when $j|n$.

Comment: @SBares: Thanks for your comment! Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1+\omega^k)^{2017}=\sum_{i=0}^{2017}\binom{2017}i\omega^{ki}\implies$$$${}$$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\sum_{i=0}^{2017}\binom{2017}i\omega^{ki}=\sum_{i=0}^{2017}\binom{2017}i\sum_{k=0}^{2016}\left(\omega^i\right)^k=\;\sum_{i=0}^{2017}\binom{2017}i\frac{1-\overbrace{\left(\omega^i\right)^{2017}}^{=1}}{1-\omega^i}=0$$

Comment: The answer is 4034

Comment: Then I have a mistake somewhere...or you have. Let us wait to see if someone else can help us out and stress where my mistake was.

Comment: ${\omega ^{ki}}$ involves index $i = 1, 2, ..., 2017$ not just index $k$. Can it be taken out of the inner $\sum {} $?

Comment: @Benedict Thank you. Yes, I know. Yet I changed the order of (*finite*) sums and, for all $\;i\;$ , we have zero there...perhaps I'll edit the answer to make this clear. In short, I don't think that is *the* mistake.

Comment: Chak's 'answer' seems to be 4034 too large.

Comment: @Benedict Thank you. That's what I thought myself, yet if the asker says that I shall wait. It can perfectly well be that I made a mistake. I though don't understand the rush to downvote, but I'm beginning to get used to that kind of things in this site. :)

Comment: @Joanpemo Was that Chak downvoting after taking a bender?

Comment: @Benedict I'm not sure what the expression "taking a bender" mean, and I don't know who did downvote.

Comment: well my teacher said that the answer to this question is 4034.

Comment: and about the downwote...i am unable to do so cause my reputation is too low

Comment: @ApratimRanChak Thank you. He could be wrong, you know? Not the strangest thing in mathematics. Anyway, it seems a little too much to downvote an answer if one doesn't even know how to prove or disprove what it presents. My opinion only, of course.

Comment: ...bender = a little tipsy?

Comment: @DonAntonio For $i=0$ and $i=2017$ you can't use the formula for the sum of geometric series since $\omega^i=1$ in these cases.

Comment: @richrow this is a **finite** sum of a geometric sequence. It can have whatever ratio at all. The ratio must be less than 1 in absolute value if we attempt to sum an *infinite* geometric series...

Comment: No, I meant that you cannot write $\omega^i-1$ in the denominator if $\omega^i=1$.

Comment: @richrow Oh, I see. You're right, of course. Since $\;\omega\;$ is a 2017th root of unity, we get $\;\omega^i\neq 1\;$ fgor all $\;0<i<2017\;$ , so the first and last summands in that sum must be done apart, and the rest stays. Thanks.